# sql to find a row where a column stops incrementing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to this.

```
creation_time           po_S            count_out_I
2012-08-03 02:45:02.133 000002029382    15974
2012-08-03 02:48:02.083 000002029382    9475
2012-08-03 02:51:02.097 000002029382    15978
2012-08-03 02:54:02.120 000002029382    15990
```

I need to find the row where count_out_I is less than the previous row when sorted by creation_time.
Database is SQL Server 2008.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This would report the first row with decreasing `count_out_I`:

```
; with  numbered as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by creation_time) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        )
select  top 1 cur.*
from    numbered cur
join    numbered prev
on      prev.rn + 1 = cur.rn
where   cur.count_out_I < prev.count_out_I
order by
        cur.rn
```